# RSA incompatibility between .NET full framework an .NET core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, rsa

I have a problem when working with RSA in .NET Full framework (4.6.2) and .net core 2. There is an existing full framework application that encrypts and decrypts files using certificates. This program is out in the wild and cannot be changed. The goal is to create a compatible .net core application that can exchange encrypted files with the existing application. In short, an symmetrical AES key is used to encrypt the actual file data. The AES key is then encrypted with the receivers public key.

I got it working 3/4 of the way.
That is:

- The full framework application can (of course) encrypt files and decrypt them.
- The .net core application can encrypt files and decrypt them.
- The .net core application can encrypt files, which can be decrypted with the full framework application.
- The .net core application **cannot** decrypt files, which have been encrypted with the full framework application.

In the last case I get an `WindowsCryptographicException` with the message `The parameter is incorrect`.

I don't get a better error message, especially not which parameter seems to be incorrect.

**Question:** What did I do wrong? ;) Or how can I figure out what parameter is wrong exactly to know what I need to change to make it work.

**Additional info and code:**

The *full 4.6.2 framework* application uses the certificate of the receiver as such:

```
var rsa = receiverCertificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
// *snip* create AES key
var encryptedAesKey = rsa.Encrypt(aesManaged.Key, false);
```

When decrypting, it does the following:

```
var rsa = receiverCertificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
// *snip* extract encrypted aes key from encrypted file
var decryptedKey = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedKey, false);
```

Now, in *.net core* it is not possible to cast the key to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

To re-use most of the existing code and port that over to .NET core I wrote these two extension methods to get an RSACryptoServiceProvider out of the keys, like this:

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetPublicKeyRsaCryptoServiceProvider(this X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
   // Get params from public key
   var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
   var rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

   var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(rsa.KeySize, new CspParameters()
   {
      ProviderType = 24,
      ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
   });
   csp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

   return rsacsp;
}

public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetPrivateKeyRsaCryptoServiceProvider(this X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
   // Get params from private key
   var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
   var rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

   var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(rsa.KeySize, new CspParameters()
   {
      ProviderType = 24,
      ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
   });
   csp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);


   return rsacsp;
}
```

The only lines I changed while porting the existing code over to .net core were the lines that casted the public/private key to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and replaced the casts with calls to my extension methods.

Before changing more and to completely move over to the RSA class from RsaCryptoServiceProvider, so that the .net core application can eventually run on other OSes, I want this to work first in a full roundtrip.

For additional info: I get hold of the `X509Certificate2` instance like this:

```
using (var myStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
   myStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   var certs = myStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage,    X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment.ToString(), true);
   return certs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Subject.Contains("receiver"));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a callstack (down to the public member you called which threw)?

Comment: Its's directly when I call `.Decrypt()` on the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: A bit more info: It's going town to `CapiHelper.DecryptKey` and from there to `CapiHelper.Interop.CryptDecrypt()` which returns with an error code. The error code is 87.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, and psychic debugging isn't working, either.  If you can come up with a publicly sharable repro please file a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues.  (For "semi-sharable", my email isn't hard to find)

Comment: I send you a repro.

Comment: How about creating a .NET Standard library for encryption/decryption which you then use in .NET and .NET core? That doesn't answer, why it is differently behaving but might be a solution.